# Adding Icons to Specific Table Column

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 2 row table in HTML. What I'm trying to do is add an image to a column if a certain condition is met. For example, if the td text is "apple" then I want to add an apple image next to it. If the td text is "orange" then I want to add an orange image next to it.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="table table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>0x3432</td>
            <td>Fruit1</td>
            <td class="demo">apple</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>0x34762</td>
            <td>Fruit2</td>
            <td class="demo">orange</td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML === "apple") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='apple.png' style='display: inline;'><p style='display: inline;'>  Apple</p>";
    }

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML === "orange"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='orange.png' style='display: inline;'><p style='display: inline;'>  Orange</p>";
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**This results in the following:**

[image]

I'm not sure why the icons are not showing up next to apple and orange.

**What I think is wrong:**

I assume that I would need a for loop for this rather than an if statement since if statements run once, but I'm not sure how I would write this.

**UPDATE:**
Updated id to class since I forgot that ids must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a foreach loop, otherwise it will just check the first one.

Also, remember that ID MUST BE UNIQUE, so you may use a class instead

Fixed to use class instead of ID:

```
<script>
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("demo"), function (el) {
    if (el.innerHTML === "apple") {
        el.innerHTML = "<img src='apple.png' style='display: inline;'><p style='display: inline;'>  Apple</p>";
    } else if (el.innerHTML === "orange"){
        el.innerHTML = "<img src='orange.png' style='display: inline;'><p style='display: inline;'>  Orange</p>";
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show me how the foreach would look like? I was updating my question when you responded with the same thing. I know it needs for, but I'm not sure how to write it. I assume td.foreach(function() { if statements });

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the code so let me know where I am wrong. You are using the empty array ([]) just so you have access to the forEach method (so you don't have to type out "Array.prototype.forEach.call"). Next you are using the call method to direct attention away from the empty array to the demo class and then you pass in a callback function which executes the conditional statements.

Comment: yes, just a shorthand of declaring the array first like: `var els = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");` and then iterating with: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {` there is no use in saving the array if you're not going to use it anywhere else.